# adding values into an array using a while loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop

So what I'm trying to do is create a live friends search. To do this I need an array of names for AJAX to search through.

Heres my while loop.

```
if($_REQUEST['D'] == 'viewfriends') {
    $FREINDS = array();
    $FRIENDS_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM `FRIENDS` WHERE `USER` = '{$Modules['User']->Username}' AND `STATUS` = 'accepted' ORDER BY `ID` Limit 10 ;";
    $FRIENDS_RESULT = mysql_query($FRIENDS_QUERY);
    if(mysql_num_rows($FRIENDS_RESULT) > 0) {
        while($FRIENDS_ROW = mysql_fetch_assoc($FRIENDS_RESULT)) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERNAME` = '{$FRIENDS_ROW['FRIEND']}' ;";
            $REQUEST_ROW = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql));
            $FRIENDS = $REQUEST_ROW['USERNAME'];
        }
    echo json_encode($FRIENDS);
    } else {
        echo'<div class="update status">Sorry, You have no friends at this time. sadface.</div>';   
    }
}
```

I put the `echo $FRIENDS` in there as a test, right now it doesn't display anything. Where did I derp?

Comment: Is this your actual code? There's a spelling mistake here: `$FREINDS = array();`

Comment: Your code is open to SQL injections, and also, why are you using the ancient `mysql_*` functions ?

Comment: im confused on the injects because its just requesting information from the database. and what do you mean by ancient mysq functions?

Comment: also yes this is my code Colin, i did fix the spelling error. no dice there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
if($_REQUEST['D'] == 'viewfriends') {
    $FRIENDS = array();
    $USERNAME = $Modules['User']->Username;
    $SQL_QUERY = "SELECT F.*, U.* FROM FRIENDS AS F LEFT JOIN USER AS U ON F.USER = U.USERNAME WHERE F.USERNAME = '{$USERNAME}' AND STATUS = 'accepted' ORDER BY F.ID LIMIT 10";
    $RESULTS = mysql_query($SQL_QUERY);
    if(mysql_num_rows($RESULTS) > 0) {
        while($ROW = mysql_fetch_assoc($RESULTS)) {           
            $FRIENDS[] = $ROW['USERNAME'];
        }
        echo json_encode($FRIENDS);
    } else {
        echo'<div class="update status">Sorry, You have no friends at this time. sadface.</div>';   
    }
}
```

---

```
 $FRIENDS[] = $REQUEST_ROW['USERNAME'];
```

then `print_r($FRIENDS);` `echo` will output `array` you need to loop the array or `echo json_encode($FRIENDS);` to see something

also are you sure that `USERNAME` is uppercase and not just `username` in lowercase lowercase as well as for the table name.

also i think you can use a `JOIN` clause instead of making to SQL requests

Comment: yes, i use the same QUERY for other functions. i do all my tables and Columns in sql as UPPERCASE to avoid this :).

Comment: yes it works great now thank you! i am confused on your SQL query though

Comment: i have used a LEFT JOIN so you don't need to make two sql request to database.

Answer (score 2):

You can't echo an array. You can use either `print_r($friends)` to display the whole row of fields requested in the query (you request *)
or you can echo `$friends['name']` (depending on how you declared name in your database)

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error:

`$FREINDS = array();` should be `$FRIENDS = array();` .

And also:

`$FRIENDS = $REQUEST_ROW['USERNAME']` should be `$FRIENDS[] = $REQUEST_ROW['USERNAME']`

And

`echo $FRIENDS;`   should be `echo json_encode( $FRIENDS );`

Comment: thank you. but it did not fix my array problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP won't actually echo out an array. If you do an echo of an array, it outputs "Array".  Plus your javascript wouldn't know what to do with a PHP array if it did pass it that way.

Try:

```
echo(json_encode($FRIENDS));
```

Also, you should really listen to the feedback in the comments. Your code is very vulnerable to attack and not set up to scale well for such a potentially huge app.

You have a couple of issues that make your code either less secure or less efficient. The most obvious inefficiency is that you are doing a database call inside your while loop, so if someone has 10 friends, that means you've done 11 database queries when you  may have only needed one or two. Here are the two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM `FRIENDS` 
WHERE `USER` = '{$Modules['User']->Username}' 
AND `STATUS` = 'accepted' ORDER BY `ID` Limit 10

SELECT * FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERNAME` = '{$FRIENDS_ROW['FRIEND']}'
```

So before we determine if these two can be combined, the first big red flag is the `SELECT *`.  I use it all of the time, but it will get you kicked out of the better database bars. In your case, it's really unnecessary.  We know from the second query that the only thing you are using from the first query is the `$FRIENDS_ROW['FRIEND']` to match against the `USERNAME`. So that first query can become:

```
SELECT FRIEND FROM `FRIENDS` 
WHERE `USER` = '{$Modules['User']->Username}' 
AND `STATUS` = 'accepted' ORDER BY `ID` Limit 10
```

You also have the `SELECT *` in the second query, and we can tell that (for now) the the only thing you are using is the `USERNAME`, so it can become:

```
SELECT USERNAME FROM `USERS` WHERE `USERNAME` = '{$FRIENDS_ROW['FRIEND']}'
```

Finally, we can see from the second query that the `FRIEND` name and the `USERNAME` are identical; otherwise why would you query for the usernames where the username equals the friend name. If that's the case, we can drop your second query completely, since we already know the usernames from the first query.

The reason why it's both inefficient and unsafe is because you are using the OG mysql functions, which are clunky and don't offer the option of prepared statements.  Prepared statements let you (among other things) put variables in your query in such a way that when you actually call the query, the parts that are variables are known and can thus be sanitized, avoiding the horrors of mysql injections that everyone has mentioned.

I won't bore you with the play-by-play, but here is what your code might look like if you used the newer mysqli library with a prepared statement:

```
if($_REQUEST['D'] == 'viewfriends') {

    $friends = array();

    $friend_lookup = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT FRIEND FROM FRIENDS WHERE 
                                               USER = ? AND STATUS = 'accepted' 
                                               ORDER BY FRIEND");

    $friend_lookup -> bind_param('s', $userName);
    $userName = $Modules['User']->Username;

    $friend_lookup -> execute();
    $friend_lookup -> bind_result($friend);

    while($friend_lookup -> fetch()) {
        $friends[] = $friend;
    }

    if($friends) {
        echo json_encode($friends);
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, no friends. Boo.";
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, and im trying to figure out where i am vulnerable? im sorry if i dont understand, i really do appreciate everone on here giving me advice.

Comment: I used the json_encode function because you said you were looking for an ajax solution. Obviously, it's not pretty if you're just trying to confirm the array is being built, in which case go with `print_r()`. But your javascript will understand the json better.

Comment: ok i understand the json_encode but everyone keeps saying my code is vulnerable for attack? why is that?

Comment: @DJ_Plus - I've updated my answer as these comment boxes are too small.

Comment: wow, thank you very much! i obviously need to revisit my mysql skills.